# Alternatives to Safari for RSS?

Tags: macos, safari, software-recommendation, rss

The 3rd party RSS Feed alternatives to Safari that *I've* found are cumbersome...in my opinion. Any simple, and good looking ones out there? (using [NetNewsWire](http://netnewswireapp.com) and it looks/feels bloated). Perhaps there's a Safari Extension?

Comment: You can always use the new News app for iOS that comes preinstalled with any device that is running iOS 9 or higher, but this is about [tag:macos], so I don't think that'll fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I use [NetNewsWire](http://www.netnewswireapp.com), but if you're coming from something simple like Safari's RSS reader, I can see how it might feel like overkill. If you don't care for NNW, have a look at [Reeder for Mac](http://reederapp.com/mac/). It's got a simpler aesthetic, perhaps more to your taste. It's [$4.99 on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder/id439845554?mt=12&ls=1), and does require a Google account, as it uses [Google Reader](https://reader.google.com/) for the backend.

Google Reader is of course another popular option, if you don't mind a web-app. You could use [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) to turn it into a bit of a hybrid app if you want a more native feel.

Comment: I second Reeder and a google reader account. It's worked flawlessly for me for many years since I left the NetNewsWire universe. I use Reeder on Mac, iPad and iPhone. All sync very well and Reeder stores things in a local cache so you can read feeds offline.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Vienna for years. It's Open Source.

http://www.vienna-rss.com/

https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss

> Vienna is an RSS/Atom reader for Mac OS X, packed with powerful features that help you make sense of the flood of information that is distributed via these formats today. The Vienna Project is continuously being improved and updated, so keep up to date with current development on the forums.
>
> Vienna is an OS X-native Objective-C/Cocoa Open Source project published under the Apache License, Version 2.0. It was started by Steve Palmer (aka stevewpalmer, stevepa) and is currently in active development by Jeff Johnson (aka johnson1234 and jeff_johnson_dev) and Michael Ströck (aka mstroeck). Many others have contributed immensely to this project, for details please download the application and load its “Acknowledgements”.
>
> Companies which have supported the project include GitHub, SourceForge (who provide all our web-hosting) and Senza Limiti.